# Запустить команду php с раскрывающегося меню Windows

Tags: php, regedit

У меня есть инструмент для форматирования текста на php по стандартам PSR-2

В консоли команда работает, файл форматируется:

```
php path/to/php-cs-fixer-v2.phar fix path/to/filename.php
```

Но когда я пытаюсь создать пункт меню в Windows через regedit - не работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При вызове пункта меню выходит диалоговое окно "Открыть с помощью", а команда даже не выполняется.

Как мне правильно указать команду в Regedit?

Comment: Полный путь до PHP исполняемого файла php.exe пытались использовать?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, Вы правы. Спасибо большое) Вынесите комментарий в ответ, и я поставлю Вам галочку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо прописать полный путь до исполняемого файла php.exe для запуска файла через shell.